# Browser console custom library

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

Sometimes i use build-in browser console to make navigation in page easier. Consider for example buttons in reddit, which, on click, redirect user  to  next page with unpredictable url(page nr isn't simply captured inside url parameter). In console i type function with jquery, that gets handler to next button and clicks it. I would like to save this function somewhere and be able to use it in console without any previous actions.

Is there a way to make my own js library, which will be added to all pages i go automatically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes: you can write yourself a [userscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript). For example, say you wanted to get that unpredictable `next` button's URL and do something with it - if you inspect reddit's HTML, you'll see that you can select the `a` with `.next-button > a`. Say you wanted to write a userscript that automatically displays the text of that URL at the top of every reddit page you go to. Install a userscript manager such as Tampermonkey, create a new script, and paste in the following:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        reddit-show-next
// @namespace   CertainPerformance
// @include     https://www.reddit.com/*
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

(() => {
  const nextAnchor = document.querySelector('.next-button > a');
  // not all pages are guaranteed to have this element, so return if it doesn't exist:
  if (!nextAnchor) return;
  const nextHref = nextAnchor.href;
  document.body.insertBefore(document.createElement('h2'), document.body.children[0])
    .textContent = nextHref;
  // or click it with the following:
  // nextAnchor.click();
})();
```

If you want to save information across pageloads, you can use `localStorage`.

Userscripts can be set to automatically run whenever you load a page that matches the `@include` you provide - that way, you don't even have to open the console. Userscripts are an incredibly powerful tool for customizing your browsing experience, but you have to know the basics of Javascript first.

If you want to scrape lots of information from multiple pages on a site with a userscript you wrote, you can use plain network requests (such as with `fetch`) rather than navigate to each page individually - it's much easier, and not hard to accomplish automatically.